# Is it possible to call a setter for name in hidden tag in struts2?

Tags: struts2, hidden, assign

In my jsp page I have a form (in struts2) in which I try to assign the size of the ArrayList data to the Vector testVector using hidden tag after submitting the form, but I still get the size of testVector equal to 0.

```
<s:hidden name="testVector.size" value="%{data.size}" />
```

I have created setters and getters for data and testVector in my Action class.

```
private Vector<String> testVector = new Vector<String>();
private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
private String testName; // a field for testing the form. 

// getters and setters of testVector and data
```

I supposed that this should work because Vector has a public setter setSize(int size).For the other field "testName" it was well submitted.. So am I have a problem in syntax?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: this will not work since your hidden field will be equivalent to `gettestVector().setSize();` while that is not the case as `testVector` is a list of string and moreover your `testVector` is of type string so i am not sure what you mean by you have getter ans setter `setSize(int size)`? i might have misread question can you show your action class code with getter and setters also

Comment: testVector is a collection of type Vector, and so it has a public method already predefined which is setSize. so I supposed that getTestVector().setSize() would be automatically called when I write name="testVector.size". But the size of testVector didn't change. This is what I mean't. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a Vector. Be aware that OGNL does not work the same from a requests as it does when rendering a JSP for security reasons, it is simply too powerful. You should just set bean properties, collections, arrays and built in types from the request (type converters ignored).

From the request in this case it thinks are are trying to put values into the vector. I think it will create a new string put it into the Vector and then try to set the size of string (which will not work because that method does not exist).

To confirm this I tried to do what you are saying and the log states:

```
WARNING: Error setting expression 'testVector.size' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@5c7b2d2f'
ognl.OgnlException: Error converting given String values for Collection. [ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: java.lang.String.size]
```

If you want this behaviour you will need to create a second method such as setSize() within your action which then goes about modifying the vector size. This I don't think is a very good thing to expose to the outside world, what if someone called your action many times passing in a huge number?